# После установки php xdebug 3.0.4, в phpinfo получаю версию 2.7.0 в чем моя ошибка? Mac OS Catalina

Tags: php, macos, mac, xdebug

установил Xdebug по этой ссылке https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina так как, у меня MacOS Catalina и из-за этого не могу запустить, phpize папки include нету в MacOS 10.15

взял свежую версию 3.0.4 и начал устанавливать, пробовал с Гита и менял версию git checkout tags/3.0.4

В итоге после всего что выполнил, в phpinfo выдает 2.7.0
Так должно быть или нет, ведь 3.0.4 поддерживает php 7.3 у меня 7.3.11

Comment: хз как ты устанавливал, но если в пыхе написана старая версия, значит ты залил в папку, а в конфиге не прописал путь к модулю, в виндосе это полный путь от корня диска.

Comment: это древняя инструкция, в Xdebug 3,0,4 уже нет xdebug.remote... вместо всех них xdebug.mode

Comment: @Jean-Claude прописал четкий путь до компилируемого файла, собственно он не работал в принципе, после установки появился, но не та версия, понял значит не актуальная статья, но в целом способ установки рабочий, странно что работает не так))) тупо пздц 
`zend_extension=/usr/php/extensions/xdebug.so`
`xdebug.mode_enable=on`
`xdebug.mode_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"` 
`xdebug.mode_host=localhost`
`xdebug.mode_handler=dbgp`
`xdebug.mode_port=9000`

Comment: у меня такой конфиг - zend_extension="d:\server\php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM

Comment: @Jean-Claude Херня в том, что работает xdebug, но она не та, вообщем, я хотел научиться разбираться в структуре и настройке Apache PHP MySql но походу, это очень долго и не стоит этих усилий сейчас, я только начинаю учиться веб-разработке
В итоге, выход только один, установить все через пакетный менеджер на Mac, а предустановленные php и apache на Mac пошли они в топку, спасибо за обратную связь дружище)

Comment: Проверь конфиги,.. для CLI, Apache, FPM они разные и учти где ты смотришь phpinfo(): если через браузер, то смотри конфиги PHP для Apache или FPM; если через консоль, то конфиг PHP для CLI.